# How do I duplicate a single post, with all its properties, and save it as a different post?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

In a wordpress plugin, how can I duplicate/clone a single post?

I would need to:
1) get a specific post
2) clear its ID property so that it's saved as a new post
3) save it.

In the process, I would like to see all the meta info + taxonomy associations preserved.

Comment: something like this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicate-post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the 'Duplicate Post' plugin at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicate-post/